# Does anyone Know how to implement this design (in swift)?

Tags: swift, dynamic, implementation

The profiles get pulled in from a server but I don't know how to implement this. Had been thinking about a dynamic table view, but I don't know if you can draw cells like that. The pictures have to be clickable.

[image]

Comment: Well,you need a UICollectionView and then insert UImageView on the UICollectionViewCell and do layer masking to makeimageview  appear as circle...thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add A `UICollectionView` to your screen. In the collection view cell, place a image view, then use this code to create the blue border and circle image...

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell:UICollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("BasicCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell



        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView


       //border 
     imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor


//make imageView Circle

imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true


        return cell
    }
```

Comment: thanks so far! but can you have two different UICollectionViews underneath each other? Or should i do everything in the same view. Because there's a spacing between them.

Comment: You have 2 options, the first one is the easiest. Option 1. Just add 3 blank collection view cells where you want there to be a space.  Option 2. Place a collection view inside a table view (Note: This is not very easy to do)

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` is probably what you're looking for (to display like on your screen capture : sections / items).

UICollectionView Class Reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/

It's *similar* as working with UITableView. Still, you might want to read some tutorials about it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is UICollectionView.  Think of it as the generic version of UITableView.